# MVC Application Not Redirecting to Custom Error Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC app that has a global error handler to take care of any internal server errors. After the handler is finished doing its work, it redirects to an Error controller to return a custom error view to the user.

My problem is this: Our custom error view used to take in a fairly complex object as its model, however I was tasked with reducing this model to a simple string value. I changed the controller from this:

```
HandleErrorInfo info = (HandleErrorInfo)RouteData.Values["exception"];
return View("Error", info);
```

To this:

```
string supportID = "..."; 
return View("Error", supportID);
```

After changing this, I am getting some weird generic error page that looks like it's coming from some default IIS asset:

[image]

Inspecting the page shows that this error page comes from this path: *assets/errorpages/http_500.html*

I even tried fully qualifying the path to my error view like so, and still get this generic error page:

```
return View("~/Views/Error/Error.cshtml", supportID);
```

I have run through this with the debugger multiple times, and there is no exception being thrown (aside from the one being handled obviously). The controller returns without any issues.

I changed this so that I am just using the ViewBag to pass in the string, which is probably a more clear solution anyway. **However**, I am still curious as to where this page is coming from and why changing the model from a complex object to a simple string is pulling a different view even when fully qualifying my view path.

Answer (score 0):

[image: My View layout]

Try:

```
          return RedirectToAction("Error");
```

Where "Error" is the name of your view.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Error Page inside 'Views\Shared'.